# Visualforce Page with an image

Tags: visualforce, images

I have a two-column page block in which I have picklist (col 1), and depending on the value selected in the picklist, an image is displayed (col 2).

My question is how do I get the image (col 2) to span rows, so that the input fields (col 1) arent pushed below the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really a semantically correct way of doing this within a page block or page block section. About the best you could do would be to absolutely position the image, which would cause the parent element to collapse, and the image itself would overflow other elements. Instead, you should consider writing your own html, which would allow you to write semantically correct code using a normal table with row spans, or even styled divs.